# Physically print webpage (div/body) to printer with same html output as rendered (no custom printer CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, printers

Javascript

What I have tried so far

```
Window.print();
```

Prints out page without my CSS layout...

The other solutions says you have to use this type of css code

```
@media print /*--This is for Print--*/ {
        .btn
        {
            display: none;
        } 
}
```

I would like to see a solution without the custom CSS stylesheet for printer with plain JS.

Thanks

Comment: Hide the button before window.print in javascript.

Comment: Just a moonshot idea: when you load the page, extract all the active styles, then create a new `<style />` with all the styles within `@media print { /* INSERT COPIED STYLES HERE */ }`. Other things will still break though (line breaks, font size, introduction of DPI and points :/.

Comment: I still dont understand why I would need a different printing stylesheet, whats the reason for having this as default?